# How To Calculate Scale Factor Of Image Based On Max Width and Height Of Different Sizes

Tags: crop

I'm trying to work out a simple calculation for working out a scale factor so that an image can fit perfectly inside a container size without stretching. This means that the original image may have to overflow the container it needs to fit in, this is fine.

The problem is the image can be of any size, it can be larger than the container in both W and H, larger in just W, larger in just H or smaller in any of those situations.

So let's say for example we have the following containing boxes:

500x500
500x1000
1000x500
300x300
200x50
50x200

and i want an image of 500x500 to fit inside them all but maintaining it's own ratio; so it will overflow some of those containers in some directions but not others.

It doesn't matter what language the code is in, i'm using JS at the moment, it's just the calculation behind it that i'm struggling with. If there was only one size container it wouldn't be too much of a problem but i'm struggling to find a one size fits all formula for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We need to see that you have made an effort

Comment: If the image can be any size and the container has a fixed max-width/max-height then it's impossible to come up a formula to make any image fit perfectly. The best you could do is get it just near perfect, and then center the image inside the container.

Comment: @Cubemaster i've tried all sorts of code, i can't just provide it, no direction works yet and the code has been deleted to start again. I find myself using IF statement after If statement to check different scenarios, i wanted to avoid it if possible.

Comment: So, for example, a 500x500 image, fitting in a 500x400 container can have 2 options: shrink to 400x400 and add black bands to the final image or just crop to 400x400 by removing bands (horizontal/vertical or vertical/horizontal). Which one do you want?\

Comment: @MattD sounds about right, seems to just depend on the situation with the images at the time. Looks like it's conditional statements galore!

Comment: @Attersson That! I forgot about the magic of adding black bands. You could do that if it doesn't make your page look too tacky.

Comment: @Attersson No, in your example the image would not have to scale at all, the 500x500 image would fit in 500x400 by overflowing the height, so no scale is needed. If the box was 500x600 it would have to scale the image in height to 600 and overflow on the width

Comment: So you want to crop.

Comment: @Attersson Essentially, yes.

Comment: On the other hand do you want a 400x400 to shrink by half in order to fit a 200x200 container or would the cropping of a central area suffice?

Comment: i almost had it working at one point, but it still messed up when the image was square and the container was rectangle because the ratio of the square. It looks like it's going to need a few conditional statements to determine which direction needs to scale up or down and then worry about if the other side (w or h) is then going to be big/small enough

Comment: @Attersson In the case of the container and image both being square, it would just scale up or down to fit perfect with no crop

Comment: I added the answer. It would be great if the wording of the question were more clear. Can you edit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to the comments, the solution can be rephrased as such:

- **Step 1** If the picture height is smaller than that of the container, upscale to fit.
- **Step 2** If the picture width is smaller than that of container, further upscale to fit.
- **Step 3** If any of step 1 and step 2 hit true, **go to Step 5**.
- **Step 4** take the smallest of (pic height - container height) and (pic width - container width). Downscale.
- **Step 5** Crop excess

Done

Note that a total of 0 or 1 upscaling or downscaling should be done at all and keeping original ratio.